# Compile/Build OpenCL program using AMD APP SDK on Linux

Tags: c, linux, opencl

I am new to OpenCL. I have written a democode [http://chopapp.com/#gh9jv1u]

I have installed the drivers and AMD APP SDK. I am using the following to compile:

`gcc –l/opt/AMDAPP/include  –L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/  open.cpp –lOpenCL`

ref:http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/

I am getting the following message:

```
gcc: error: –l/opt/AMDAPP/include: No such file or directory
gcc: error: –L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64/: No such file or directory
gcc: error: –lOpenCL: No such file or directory
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

```
gcc -I/opt/AMDAPP/include -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64 open.c -lOpenCL
```

Hope this helps all nascent opencl programmers!

Answer (score 0):

You may check the path hint by gcc error. May be you SDK is not install in /opt/AMDAPP.
And the last error, `–lOpenCL: No such file or directory`, make sure the libOpenCLXXX.so.XXX is in the /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib or /libs. It seems you haven't install the SDK properly.

Comment: /opt/AMDAPP/include/CL $ ls -->
cl_d3d10.h  cl_d3d11.h  cl_dx9_media_sharing.h  cl_ext.h  cl_gl_ext.h  cl_gl.h  cl.h  cl.hpp  cl_platform.h  opencl.h | 

/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64 $ ls -->
libamdocl64.so  libGLEW.so  libglut.so  libOpenCL.so  libOpenCL.so.1

Looks fine to me!